# Symfony form submission DateTime format

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony/twig to generate a simple form to create a blog post. I'm trying to use doctrine to save the date of the post submission. My problem is, I don't know how to get the current date into an acceptable format.

My entity has this:

```
public function setSubtime(\DateTimeInterface $subtime): self
    {
        $this->subtime = $subtime;

        return $this;
    }
```

and I'm trying to do this:

```
$date = date('H:i:s \O\n d/m/Y');
$post->setSubtime($date);
```

but this throws the `App\Entity\Post::setSubtime() must implement interface DateTimeInterface` error.

So my question is, what kind of date format will it accept?

To clarify what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to get the current date (not time, just date) at the time of post submission and then save it to the "Post" database table. My "Subtime" column is of type `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `setSubtime` must be an instance of DateTimeInterface.

The `date` function returns a formatted date string. So I think you should convert it to `DateTimeInterface`.

Or use the DateTime class:

```
$post->setSubtime(new DateTime('H:i:s \O\n d/m/Y'));
```